# Azure functions migrating from in-process to isolated .Net Core

Tags: azure, function

I have migrated a .Net Core In-process application to Isolated mode.
It uses blobtriggers and although the application name has remained the same [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s77iF.png) the sub folder of the app has changed to Host.Function.

This means it attempts to process old blobs.  Can anyone help on how to change the folder name that is used? Its not the app name for which I have found other posts online. It is the subfolder after this.

So before it was:
**App.Functions.ProcessBlob.Run**
It has become
**Host.Functions.ProcessBlob**

How to force back other than copies millions of files please?

Comment: I am also running into this issue. I am very surprised by this behavior change and am struggling to find any documentation around it. Did you ever find a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can update the namespace in all the files in your project from App.Functions to Host.Functions. Also, Check this [Github Document](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/azure-functions/migrate-version-3-version-4.md#package-and-namespace-changes) to change all the Files and **add** **Program.cs** file in your Project as Isolated Function requires Program.cs to run your Function which is not required by in process function.

You can directly add the desired path in your Isolated **`Function1.cs`** like below:-

```cs
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace FunctionApp71
{
    public class Function1
    {
        private readonly ILogger<Function1> _logger;

        public Function1(ILogger<Function1> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        [Function(nameof(Function1))]
        public async Task Run([BlobTrigger("test/{name}", Connection = "blobconnection")] Stream stream, string name)
        {
            using var blobStreamReader = new StreamReader(stream);
            var content = await blobStreamReader.ReadToEndAsync();
            _logger.LogInformation($"C# Blob trigger function Processed blob\n Name: {name} \n Data: {content}");
        }
    }
}
```

In the above code
Run([BlobTrigger("test/{name}", Connection = "blobconnection")] Stream stream, string name)

**test** is the name of the container, Replace this with your new container.

**Program.cs:-**

```cs
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults()
    .ConfigureServices(services =>
    {
        services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService();
        services.ConfigureFunctionsApplicationInsights();
    })
    .Build();

host.Run();
```

**host.json:-**

```json
{
    "version": "2.0",
    "logging": {
        "applicationInsights": {
            "samplingSettings": {
                "isEnabled": true,
                "excludedTypes": "Request"
            },
            "enableLiveMetricsFilters": true
        }
    }
}
```

**local.settings.json:-**

```json
{
    "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet-isolated",
    "blobconnection": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=xxxxstore;AccountKey=xxxxxxxgNw==;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net"
  }
}
```

***FunctionApp71.csproj:-***

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <UserSecretsId>b0ff1c46-169c-4fb8-87c1-f0bdc86f226f</UserSecretsId>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Azure.Storage.Blobs" Version="12.13.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Azure.Storage.Files.Shares" Version="12.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Azure.Storage.Queues" Version="12.11.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker" Version="1.20.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Storage.Blobs" Version="6.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk" Version="1.16.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WorkerService" Version="2.21.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.ApplicationInsights" Version="1.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Azure" Version="1.5.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets" Version="6.0.1" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Using Include="System.Threading.ExecutionContext" Alias="ExecutionContext" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

**Output:-**

When I added one  Blob in the test container of the Storage Account my Function got triggered:-

[image]

Here's my [Github Repository](https://github.com/sid24desai/BlobTriggerIsolated) with BlobTrigger Isolated for your reference.

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed answer. I don't think I explained the issue very well however because it is the blob receipts folder that gets created which I am looking to change.

This appears in the azure-webjobs folder.

Comment: azure-webjobs is created automatically. Even if you delete it, It will be created automatically

Comment: @SiddheshDesai - yes what the OP is referencing is that the naming convention used for the blob receipts within azure-webjobs seems to have changed which is causing blobs that were already processed to be triggered again after upgrading.